# Intercept messages against Virtual Topic before being sent to consumer queue in ActiveMQ

Tags: mqtt, activemq-classic, iot, qos, virtual-topic

Is there any way to edit messages sent to a Virtual Topic before they are dispatched to consumer queue in ActiveMQ. I need to change the persistence property in the message before it is consumed by the queue.

Is there any plugin or already built in functionality for that?
My main goal is to persist messages of QoS level 0

Comment: What problem do you think persisting a QOS 0 message will solve? and why can't you fix the publisher if needed?

Comment: Because I can't change the publishing client, that is the issue, it only sends messages with QoS level 0 and the device is not capable of higher QoS levels

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality to change the QoS of an incoming MQTT message. Also, there is no available plugin that I'm aware of to do this either. You would need to write your own.